# bs выдает пустой массив

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup

Указываю тег и класс, выдаёт пустой массив, пробовал разный синтаксис

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.binance.com/ru/trade/DOGE_BTC'
HEADERS = {'user-agent': ну тут код, 'accept': '*/*'}

def get_html (url, params=None):
    r = requests.get (url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r



def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup (html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all ('div', class_='text')

    print (items)


def parse ():
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        get_content (html.text)
    else:
        print ('Error')


parse()
```

Comment: Пытались разобраться в чем проблема? Например, сравнив код страницы в браузере и то, что вернул `requests.get`? Скорее всего, данные, что вы ищите загружаются после получения страницы, в js, а у requests/bs4 нет js-движка, поэтому и нет тех данных. Посмотрите в сторону selenium, сможете разобраться, сами оформите ответ, нет -- спросите в этом же вопрос :)

Comment: не могу с помощью selenium

Comment: через selenium все равно не ищет, ищу через class, в консоли пишет что ничего не нашел, как так я не понимаю

Comment: Возможно, где-то вы ошиблись, добавил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте через [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium). Скорее всего, данные, что вы ищите загружаются после получения страницы, в js, а у requests/bs4 нет js-движка, поэтому и нет тех данных

Пример:

```
import traceback

# pip install selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
# options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
try:
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    driver.get('https://www.binance.com/ru/trade/DOGE_BTC')
    print(f'Title: {driver.title!r}')

    for x in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.text'):
        print(x.text)
    
    # 15,579,080
    # 6.54321360
    # 12,719,375
    # 5.21494375
    # 35,420,191
    # 14.16807640
    # ...

except:
    print(traceback.format_exc())

finally:
    # driver.quit()
    pass
```

Comment: через selenium так и не разобрался, да и понял что парсить так все долго будет, нашел в networke откуда подгружаются эти значения, но не понимаю как к ним обратится, чтобы их в переменную записать

Comment: @relict, смотрите через инспектора в структуру страницы, кст, если мой ответ вам помог, то пожалуйста [проголосуйте и отметитьте ответ как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Comment: отмечу) у меня немного другой вопрос, я вытащил ссылку где нужные мне данные https://www.binance.com/api/v3/depth?symbol=DOGEBTC&limit=1000
похоже на массив, как мне теперь вытащить оттуда некоторые значения и дать эти значения переменным?

Comment: @relict, используйте `requests`: `import requests` + `rs = requests.get('https://www.binance.com/api/v3/depth?symbol=DOGEBTC&limit=1000')` +  `print(rs.json())`, останется обработать словарь из ответа на запросы -- вытащить значения по ключу и т.п.